# The fastest way to get redirect URL using PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect, curl

How can I get true URL ASAP ? I need to check big number of URLs in a single script (max execution time - 30 sec).

CURL solution takes too much time. I found something like this:

```
function get_URL($url)
{
    $headers = @get_headers($url);
    $pattern = '/Location\s*:\s*(https?:[^;\s\n\r]+)/i';
    if ($locations = preg_grep($pattern, $headers))
    {
        preg_match($pattern, end($locations), $redirect);
        return $redirect[1];
    }
    return $url;
}
```

which seems to works faster. Are there any other, faster ways?

Comment: Can you clarify? "Get the true URL" = get the URL of the current page in the browser? Can't you just use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] or one of those variables?

Comment: It's not going to get any faster than that without using more than one process

Comment: @Eric: I think he means checking if the URL redirects anywhere, then returning that URL

Comment: It won't make much difference, but you can speed up your function by defining pattern (which is constant throughout) outside of the function so you're not redefining the variable each time. That's going to make minimal difference though in comparison to finding the fastest functions to use (which I can't help with).

Comment: Yes, I mean the true URL, after redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the CURL "multi" feature, which allows you to make multiple requests simultaneously without having to manage multiple processes yourself.

The [PHP documentation for curl_multi_init()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) has some basic examples.
Another tutorial is available [here](http://www.somacon.com/p537.php).

Also, if PHP's max execution time is the only thing stopping you and you don't *actually* care if it takes longer than 30 seconds you can always call [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) on each iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` contains the previous URL which redirected to the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, from [here](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php):

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for. I want to get URL after redirect.